# How do I make GridSeachCV work with a custom transformer in my pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

If I exclude my custom transformer the GridSearchCV runs fine, but with, it errors. 
Here is a fake dataset:

```
import pandas
import numpy
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn_pandas import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import sklearn_pandas
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pandas.DataFrame({"Letter":["a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d"],
                       "Number":[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 
                       "Label":["G","G","B","B","G","G","B","B","G","G","B","B","G","G","B","B"]})

class MyTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, x, **transform_args):
        x["Number"] = x["Number"].apply(lambda row: row*2)
        return x

    def fit(self, x, y=None, **fit_args):
        return self

x_train = df
y_train = x_train.pop("Label")    

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    ("Number", MinMaxScaler()),
    ("Letter", LabelBinarizer()),
    ])

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("custom", MyTransformer()),
    ("mapper", mapper),
    ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier()),
    ])


param_grid = {"classifier__min_samples_split":[10,20], "classifier__n_estimators":[2,3,4]}

model_grid = sklearn_pandas.GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, verbose=2, scoring="accuracy")

model_grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

and the error is

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I make GridSearchCV work while there is a custom transformer in my pipeline?

Comment: can you add in your `import` statements, so i can run your code?

Comment: +1 for previous comment. No time to look at code that doesn't work up to the point where it reproduces the error. It may be necessary to inherit from `BaseEstimator` as well as `TransformerMixin`, but I the error doesn't seem to point in that direction. Also a full traceback would have been nice ...

Comment: I get a different error: `AttributeError: 'MyTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_params'`

Comment: Yes, you need to add BaseEstimator to the list of super-classes for your estimator.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but it looks like the problem is with the non-numeric feature. It works fine when you take it out of `df`. The issue is probably that, when the features are all numeric, the `DataFrame` can be coerced to a Numpy `array`, but when there are non-numeric features it is coerced to a `list` instead. You can see this if you put `print(type(x))` in `MyTransformer.transform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer comes rather late, but I've encountered the same behavior with sklearn and `BaseSearchCV` derivative classes. The problem actually seems to stem from the `_PartitionIterator` class in the sklearn cross_validation module, as it makes the assumption that everything emitted from every `TransformerMixin` class in the pipeline is going to be array-like, and thus it generates slices of indices that are used to index incoming `X` args in a array-like manner. Here's the [`__iter__`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L80) method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    ind = np.arange(self.n)
    for test_index in self._iter_test_masks():
        train_index = np.logical_not(test_index)
        train_index = ind[train_index]
        test_index = ind[test_index]
        yield train_index, test_index
```

And the `BaseSearchCV` grid search metaclass calls cross_validation's [`_fit_and_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1484), which uses a method called `safe_split`. Here's the relevant line:

```
X_subset = [X[idx] for idx in indices]
```

This will absolutely produce unexpected results if X is a pandas dataframe, which you're emitting from your `transform` function.

There are two ways I've found to fix this:

1. Make sure to return an array from your transformer:

   ```
   return x.as_matrix()
   ```
2. This is a hack. If the pipe of transformers demands the input to the next transformer be a DataFrame, as was my case, you can write a utilities script that is essentially the same as the sklearn `grid_search` module, but includes some clever validation methods that are called in the `_fit` method of the `BaseSearchCV` class:

   ```
   def _validate_X(X):
       """Returns X if X isn't a pandas frame, otherwise 
       the underlying matrix in the frame. """
       return X if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame) else X.as_matrix()

   def _validate_y(y):
       """Returns y if y isn't a series, otherwise the array"""
       if y is None:
           return y

       # if it's a series
       elif isinstance(y, pd.Series):
           return np.array(y.tolist())

       # if it's a dataframe:
       elif isinstance(y, pd.DataFrame):
           # check it's X dims
           if y.shape[1] > 1:
               raise ValueError('matrix provided as y')
           return y[y.columns[0]].tolist()

       # bail and let the sklearn function handle validation
       return y
   ```

As an example, [here's my "custom grid_search module"](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/skutil/blob/master/skutil/grid_search.py).

Answer (score 0):

Short version: pandas and scikit-learn's *cross validation methods* didn't like to talk in that way (in my version, 0.15); this may be fixed simply by updating scikit-learn to 0.16/stable or 0.17/dev.

The `GridSearchCV` class validates the data and converts it to an array (so that it can perform CV splits correctly). So you don't get to use Pandas DataFrame features inside of built-in cross validation loops.

You will have to make your own cross-validation routines that don't do the validation if you want to do this kind of thing.

EDIT: This is my experience with scikit-learn's cross validation routines. It is why sklearn-pandas provides cross_val_score. However, so far as I can tell, GridSearchCV is not specialized by sklearn-pandas; your import of it accidentally imports the default sklearn version. Therefore, you may have to implement you own grid search using [ParameterGrid](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid.html#sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid) and sklearn-pandas's cross_val_score.

Comment: That's just not true. All you need in a `Pipeline` is any object with a `fit` and `transform` method that returns an array and takes the right positional arguments (array `x`, one-d optional array `y`)

Comment: @ssdecontrol  Thank you, you are quite correct. I forgot that it was cross-validation, not Pipeline's, that cause the problem.

Comment: Andreus I've never had a problem with that either.

Comment: Sorry, I know I sounded a bit curt there, @ssdecontrol. I've added an edit which I hope explains what my experience has been. Your link does not appear to reference anything related to cross validation; am I missing something?

Comment: I thought I'd updated the Gist linked in the question. The point is that I had no problem running `GridSearchCV` with my custom `Selector` class. I'm actually scratching my head over why that works but this doesn't.

Comment: It looks like this may be fixed in later versions of scikit-learn. I am currently using 0.15.x, but the live source code has [explicit code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L195) for checking if the array is a pandas dataframe (the mention of 'iloc').

Comment: I'm using the latest version and it's still broken for me. I think the difference is that in my data there weren't any non-numeric features. That is probably affecting any internal coercion processes.